# Compile Openssl with MinGW on Windows - fatal error: openssl/md4.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, windows, openssl, mingw

I did:

1. Installed MinGW+MSYS
2. Installed ActivePerl
3. Added all I need to the PATH
4. Downloaded latest Openssl and unzipped it into C:\openssl
5. Did in my `cmd.exe`: perl Configure mingw shared --prefix=/c/openssl
6. `make depand`
7. `make`
8. `make install`
9. cded to C:\cpp where I have my test.cpp :

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md4.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char digest[MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char string[] = "hello world";

    MD4((unsigned char*)&string, strlen(string), (unsigned char*)&digest);    

    char mdString[33];

    for(int i = 0; i < MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

    printf("md4 digest: %s\n", mdString);

    return 0;
}
```

Tried to compile it and got this:

```
C:\cpp>g++ test.cpp -lcrypto
test.cpp:3:25: fatal error: openssl/md4.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Find the directory where the included file, `openssl/md4.h`, is installed and include that directory in the command.

For example, if the full path of `openssl/md4.h` is `c:\openssl\include\openssl\md4.h`, your command would become:

```
g++ -Ic:\openssl\include tst.cpp -lcrypto
```

Comment: it gave me this: `C:\cpp>g++ -Ic:\openssl-1.0.1e\include\ test.cpp -lcrypto
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @mazix find the path of the libcrypto binary and add the path to `g++` with `-L` option the same way you did for `-I`.